# Reloading tableView when subclassed causing crash

Tags: iphone, objective-c, crash, uitableview, reloaddata

Hey guys! I have some problems **reloading** my tableView.
I have subclasses my tableView, with a class called **RadioTable**. I have also subclasses my TableViewCells, but thats not important here.

I need to point out that i'm pretty new, and built my subclass from some tutorials and stuff.

First of all, here is the **error message** i'm getting when i try to reload my data.
I am reloading it with [self.tableView reloadData].

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UITableViewController loadView] loaded the "MainView" nib but didn't get a UITableView.'
```

Okay, so the problem is pretty clear. The view(my nib-file) does not have any tableView's connected to the Files Owner. And thats what i tried to solve. I tried to add a IBOutlet in my subclass, and setting the tableView-property there.

*(My tableView-subclass is inherited from UITableView, just so thats clear)*

Here is my **init-code:**

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style {

 if ((self = [super initWithStyle:style])){
  RadioTable *aTableView = [[RadioTable alloc] initWithFrame:self.tableView.frame style:style];
  [aTableView setDelegate:self];
  [aTableView setDataSource:self];
  [aTableView setSwipeDelegate:self];
  [aTableView setRowHeight:54];

     [self setTableView:aTableView];
        [self.tableView setScrollEnabled:NO];
        [self.tableView setRowHeight:80];
        [self.tableView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine];
        [self.tableView setSeparatorColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
  [aTableView release];

 }

 return self;
}
```

The tableView works fine when i launch the app, it works **perfect**. But the problem occours when i try to **reload** it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this will solve your problem, but don't create your view controller's view in its init method. Instead, override `loadView` and create the table view in that method. And assign the table not only to the `tableView` property but also to the view controller's `view` property.

See the documentation for `loadView` and `viewDidLoad` for more info.